# How to sell PDFs using PayPal Cart

Tags: paypal

What can I do to be able to sell downloadable PDFs using PayPal Cart? I plan to have a business account set up. The PDFs will be hosted on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Paypal API, follow the steps listed.(They are simple and you may find lots of tutorials too.)
Successful transactions give you a transaction id, use that id on pdf download page. If it's valid, allow the user to download, else throw the error.

Comment: what do you mean by get api? Do i need to download it to my server?

Comment: I also will have physical goods and I use Add to Cart button. Is it possible to have it all combined? Ie - when the user adds a bunch of physical goods and a downloadable pdf, they can pay for it all at once. If so, could you point me to a place where it is explained how to set this up. thank you.

Comment: if you are using some CMS like Joomla, Chances are there are already plugins for it. It is possible to combine everything together. Let me find the link.

Comment: maybe this can help, if you are using PHP, http://www.phpwebcommerce.com/php-mysql-shopping-cart-tutorial.php

Comment: Thanks. But I don't need a shopping cart. I am using Paypal shopping cart to avoid writing my own from scratch.